# pattern with recursion(python)

Tags: python, recursion

so we are assigned with a program where it asks for two kinds of symbols and then asks for a number, which is the width of the patter.
example:

```
string 1: *
string 2 :^
width : 4

****
**^^
^^^^
**^^
****
```

and for odd numbers

```
string 1: *
string 2: ^
width: 5

*****
***^^
*^^^^
***^^
*****
```

we are supposed to use recursion for this

SO I've just been confused and puzzled by how to make the two strings weave, meaning that how would I make the second column have ***^^, I've been able to write the frame code for this it is the relationship between them that I can't do.

Answer (score 3):

The following recursive solution uses [`str.rjust(width[, fillchar])`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html) with an appropriate `fillchar`:

```
def pat(s1, s2, width, i=0):
    # formula for the number of s2 ('^') in the i-th row
    x = 2 * (width//2 - abs(i - width//2))  # works for even and odd n
    if x >= 0:  # base case: negative number of s2
        print((s2 * x).rjust(width, s1))  # output row
        pat(s1, s2, width, i+1)  # recursive call

>>> s1 = '*'
>>> s2 = '^'
>>> pat(s1, s2, 4)
****
**^^
^^^^
**^^
****
>>> pat(s1, s2, 5)
*****
***^^
*^^^^
***^^
*****
>>> pat(s1, s2, 6)
******
****^^
**^^^^
^^^^^^
**^^^^
****^^
******
```